# cellForRowAtIndexPath: method in UITableViewDelegate

Tags: ios, uitableview

Can please someone explain how to use of a cache to “re-queue” table row cells, and is this approach really useful, how does it improve the performance?

Comment: I don't want to be rude or mean, but you should try google just a little bit, check the results, do a little of research and after that, if you don't understand something post it on SO.

Answer (score 2):

reUsing of cell object by cell identifier increase the performance. as some basic point of objective C

- when you allocate and instantiate a object it get some memory space. and the process of allocation and initialisation of that memory space need some time and internal processing.

so as for your query reUsing a cell in cellForRowAtIndexpath avoid that recursive process of allocation and deallocation. in simple word if a cell is not in a display then there is no point to give memory to that cell.

as a mobile developer we always take care of one thing that operating system have limited resource. and a good operating system is a system which respond to every process in a good manner. so in iOS if you dont take about the memory issue then this may be lead to kill your app by iOS when he need to give that memory to other app. ARC takecare of this thing but you should also take care of this issue that there is no memory leak in the app. or you are not using a more memory than required for your app.

Answer (score 1):

A table view may have thousands of rows, and if each row existed "forever" as a cell (UIView) then storage problems would often occur.

So iOS discards cells that are scrolled off the edge of the screen and places them in a reuse queue, such that there are never more than maybe 30 cells (depending on screen and cell size) in existence at a time.

Reusing cells from a reuse pool (vs creating new ones) saves iOS the overhead of allocating and initializing new cells and saves your app the overhead of "customizing" them with colors, backgrounds, etc.  But of course the cell-unique data (eg, the name and phone number in a phone list) must be "refreshed" when the cell is recycled.  So it's important that the app keep some other data source (typically an NSArray) to contain ALL the "raw" data in the table.